# how to extend Java Virtual Memory in CentOS?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, server

as I wrote on the title, I want to extend Virtual Memory while performing my java code. 
currently, I'm writing a code for word Analyzer. In eclipse if there are 1000 number of inputs then it gives 1000 fine outputs. however when I run it from a server, it gives 80% outputs and 20% for null. after that I asked this problem to someone I know and he said it is because of small size of Virtual Memory in the server.

I normally run the java program with .sh file and content of the .sh file is written as below.

```
export JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64"
PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
export JAVA_HOME

java -cp /home/account/count_con.jar countConversation.countCon_Starter &
```

and then type "bash .sh file".

Please give me your kind advice for how to run java code with extra Virtual memory size in server(OS:CentOS).

Thank you

Comment: -Xms256m will set the memory to 256 Mb, change the number as you like

Comment: You said, "while performing my code."   The -Xmx option mentioned by others is a Java command-line option that sets the size of the heap _before_ your code starts running.  I have not heard of any JVM that lets you change the size of the heap while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

after java command set the flag -Xmx**size**m

FYI

Xms is initial Java heap size

Xmx is maximum Java heap size

Xss is java thread stack size

Comment: for adding flag -Xmx1024m I tried to modify the .sh file by  adding "export JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx1024m"" before java -cp /home.... or "-Xmx1024m after java -cp /home..." but seems like both of 2 ways didn't work property. Have I done something wrong with it?